# Can you access lines below the one being read in Python?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to write a text-based adventure in Python, for which I created a class called `Room`. A `Room` consists of a description and 4 other `Room`s in each direction (north, south, ...).

But when I create, for instance, two rooms next to each other, I have to create one of them first, meaning it can't understand what I pass as the `Room` next to it because it's a line below.

I was wondering what ways there are to fix such a problem, other than perhaps making and importing a new file for each room. I'll add a small example.

```
room_north = Room("RoomNorth", room_south)
room_south = Room("RoomSouth", room_north)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I wonder if there's a word for this. It's sort of like a circular dependency.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest approach would be to create the rooms first, and then assert the inter-room data. Class Room might have a method:
Room.set_adjacent_room(direction, value)

Comment: Thanks, I´ll definitely try some things out, I think I was hoping I could make it really easy for myself ^^

Answer (score 2):

One way is to change your `Room` class so that it doesn't need the connections at construction. First create the rooms, and then add the connections:

```
room_north = Room("RoomNorth")
room_south = Room("RoomSouth")
room_north.south = room_south
room_south.north = room_north
```

Another way is restructure your code to store all rooms in a dictionary, identified by strings:

```
rooms = {
  "room_north": Room("RoomNorth", "room_south"),
  "room_south": Room("RoomSouth", "room_north"),
}
```

A possible drawback is that every lookup of a room will have to go through this dictionary, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I was just wondering if it might be possible to simply create every Room like this: room_test = Room(), and then later do it again but fill the brackets?